# Updating the Map location in iOS

Tags: ios, maps

I have two response from the server( longitude and latitude). This response is save and display to the Table cell. When clicking the cell, there is a map with the location given by the server. How can i update the location of the map (move the marker) depending on the server given response?

Here is my code in map:

@interface ChildDetailViewController ()

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

@implementation ChildDetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    MapAnnotation *mapPoint = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
    mapPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self.appDelagate.latitude doubleValue], [self.appDelagate.longitude doubleValue]);
    mapPoint.title = self.appDelagate.name;
    mapPoint.mapimage = self.appDelagate.image;

    // Add it to the map view
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:mapPoint];

    // Zoom to a region around the pin
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapPoint.coordinate, 500, 500);

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];


}


#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"MapAnnotation";

    // Return a MKPinAnnotationView with a simple accessory button

    view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(!view)
    {
        view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        view.canShowCallout = YES;
        view.animatesDrop = YES;
    }

    return view;
}
```

Here is the code in Table Cell:

```
#import "ChildListViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Child.h"
#import "ChildDetailViewController.h"


@interface ChildListViewController ()
{
    NSArray *_child_info;
    //NSString *locationName;
}


@end

@implementation ChildListViewController


- (IBAction)unwindchild:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];



    NSLog(@"Pumasok ba?");
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TableIdentifier";

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [_child_info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    Child *cell = (Child *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Child" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.childName.text = appDelegate.name;
    cell.childbeaconID.text = appDelegate.beacon_id;
    cell.childstatus.text = appDelegate.status;
    cell.childLoclong.text = appDelegate.longitude;
    cell.childLoclat.text = appDelegate.latitude;
    cell.serverCreatedDate.text = appDelegate.server_created_date;
    cell.childimageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                                        [NSURL URLWithString:appDelegate.image]]];

return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_child_info count];
 }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return 119;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.name != nil)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:(@"a") sender:(self)];
    }
    else
    {

        NSLog(@"No Data %@", appDelegate.name);
    }
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
            ChildDetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            vc.appDelagate = [_child_info objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Parse the server response
AppDelegate.m

```
 NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary =[userPushInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
            NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryalert = [fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"alert"];
            NSDictionary *fetchedDictionarybody = [fetchedDictionaryalert objectForKey:@"body"];
            NSDictionary *fetchedDictionaryresult = [fetchedDictionarybody objectForKey:@"student_event"];
            for (NSDictionary *user in  fetchedDictionaryresult)
            {

                    beacon_device_name =[user  objectForKey:@"beacon_device_name"];
                    image =[user objectForKey:@"image"];
                    latitude = [user objectForKey:@"latitude"];
                    longitude =[user objectForKey:@"longitude"];
                    server_created_date = [user objectForKey:@"server_created_date"];
                    status =[user objectForKey:@"status"];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update by doing this after you get the response

```
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.mapView.annotations];

MapAnnotation *mapPoint = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
mapPoint.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([newLatitude doubleValue], [newLongitude doubleValue]);
mapPoint.title = self.appDelagate.name;
mapPoint.mapimage = self.appDelagate.image;

// Add it to the map view
[self.mapView addAnnotation:mapPoint];

// Zoom to a region around the pin
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapPoint.coordinate, 500, 500);

[self.mapView setRegion:region];
```

you can communicate within the view controllers by using Notification Center,put the first in your child view controller,and second after parse your response.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLocation) name:AppDelegateReceiveTheLocation object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AppDelegateReceiveTheLocation object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: Sir, Map Marker don't move. It's not updating sir

Comment: could you show the code how you parse and save location in the response

Comment: You can edit you question to post more code,Arndroid.

Comment: Actually i parse the server response in AppDelegate , then i send it to another view controller which is ChildListViewController it display in a list of a table.. then after displaying it... when you click the cell , the can see the map location but it not update

Comment: after you parse and save the location,you should let ChildDetailViewController knows and do the change location thing.You can use NSNotification to do this.

Comment: But the response that i receive is in the app delegate  then how can i update also the child detail view controller if the data is in the app delegate?